# When and how was the water cycle discovered?

Tags: discoveries, earth-sciences

When and how was the water cycle discovered? Did people, like ancient Greek philosophers, have any correct ideas on the water cycle?  Was its discovery more of a recent thing?

Comment: Some argue that the [water cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cycle#History_of_hydrologic_cycle_theory) was completely understood by Hebrew scholars as evidenced by the text fom the Hebrew bible dated as early as the 10th century BCE.

Comment: "*The first published thinker to assert that rainfall alone was sufficient for the maintenance of rivers was Bernard Palissy (1580 CE), who is often credited as the "discoverer" of the modern theory of the water cycle. Palissy's theories were not tested scientifically until 1674, in a study commonly attributed to Pierre Perrault.*"

Comment: It was understood in a general way in the ancient world.

Comment: This article discusses this topic of the water cycle. I recommend giving it a read: [Science and the Bible](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/science-and-the-bible/)

Answer (score 6):

In Aristotles *Meteorology*, we have:

> Now, the sun, moving as it does, sets up processes of change and becoming and decay, and by it's agency the finest and the sweetest water is carried up and is dissolved into vapour and rises to the upper region, where it is condensed again by the cold and so returns the earth.

And he notes this again in his *Physics* that:

> Zeus does not send the rain in order to make the corn grow: it comes of neccessity. The stuff which has been drawn up is bound to cool, and having cooled, turns to water and comes down. It is merely concurrent that this having happened, the corn grows.

Hence, the hydrological or water cycle, at least in Europe, was known by Aristotles time, and so by 350 BCE.